# Copied Crystal Reports Query and it does not return any data in SQL Studio

Tags: sql, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010

I copied the query directly from Crystal Reports and removed the quotations that crystal includes in their query. No data is returned in SQL Studio. I am not sure what is causing this.

```
 SELECT APTH.Mth, APTH.APTrans, APTH.Vendor, APVM.Name, APTH.APRef,
        APTH.InvDate, APTH.DueDate, APWH.UnpaidAmt, APWH.APCo

 FROM   (APTH 
 INNER JOIN APVM ON (APTH.Vendor=APVM.Vendor) AND 
                    (APTH.VendorGroup=APVM.VendorGroup)) 

 INNER JOIN APWH ON ((APTH.APCo=APWH.APCo) AND 
                     (APTH.VendorGroup=APWH.VendorGroup)) AND 
                     (APTH.APTrans=APWH.APTrans)

 WHERE  APWH.UnpaidAmt>0 AND APWH.APCo=100
```

Comment: Does it still return no data if you remove the where clause from the query?  It's possible your query returned no results because no records matched the conditions specified in the where clause.

Comment: Yikes, thank you. That filter or "Where" clause is working in crystal reports though and returns data but it does not in SQL.

Comment: Sounds like there may be some difference in syntax in SQL Studio versus Crystal Reports.  Which DBMS are you using?